# QByteArray to to 'bitstream' output

Tags: c++, qt4, pthreads, qbytearray

I have issues with the following code. I am trying to transmit a QByteArray through a shared bool value (data) between two threads which write and read the data, communicating via 'syncs' and 'ack' bools [Emulating a communications protocol over wires]. Unfortunately when I try to convert the output QByteArray to a bool output, I get an 'ASSERT:' error. Below is the relevant code and output.

```
void* write(void* wind)
{
// Initialization
int i,b;
Window *w = (Window *)wind;

qDebug() << "Write thread started.";

// Write Loop
while(!w->exit)
{
    if(w->enqueue == true)
    {
        // Reset Trigger
        w->enqueue = false;
        QByteArray cachedByteArray(w->byteArrayOut);

        // Convert from QByteArray to QBitArray
        qDebug() << "Starting bit stream" << endl;
        for(i=0; i<(cachedByteArray.count()); ++i)
        {
            qDebug() << "Byte: " << i << endl;
            for(b=0; b<8; ++b)
            {
                qDebug() << "Bit: " << b << endl;
                data = cachedByteArray.at(i)&(1<<b);
                qDebug() << "Sent Bit: " << b << endl;
                syncs = true;
                while(!ack); // Wait for bit to be read
                syncs = false;
                while(ack); // Wait for read thread to be ready
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Write thread started. 

Starting bit stream 

Byte:  0 

Bit:  0 

Sent Bit:  0 

Bit:  1 

ASSERT: "i >= 0 && i < size()" in file /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qbytearray.h, line 414
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

As you can see from the debug messages, the loop works for the first iteration, but crashes on the output of the second bit. I have checked other code sources for conversion between QByteArray and bits and the syntax is correct as far as I can tell.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What valid reason do you have to communicate 1 bit at a time?  Are you trapped in a cell somewhere, only able to use a lightbulb switch?  If so, can you pre-arrange a protocol with other prisoners who also use the room?

Comment: The data will eventually be sent over a connection to the GPIO, however first I wanted to get the communications working virtually, then add in the GPIO functions.

Comment: Ah, you do have a lightbulb!  Your first problem might be the compiler optimizing `while(!ack);` to something like `ack=true;`, as that is legal under C++ (all loops must do IO or terminate: thus an infinite loop over a non-IO value is an assertion that the value is set to true).  And the memory model of C++ is even stranger: I don't see any mention of `atomic` variables.  C++ memory model makes sense for single-threaded execution, in multi-threaded cases without synchronization the optimizer is free to do changes that do not align with what you imagine would happen.

Comment: At the moment I am compiling under the 'debug' build (not release). As far as I am aware the debug compilation process involves no optimization?